# Print instantiation chain

Tags: c++, debugging, instantiation, typename

I'm debugging some C++ parser with STL C++0x containers (toolchain is GCC 4.7.0).

And since the STL rebind code is hardly understandable, I need to somehow print the full chain of instantiations for a typedef like `std::vector<T>::reference`. Of course, it resolves just to `T&`, but before it goes through at least 7 different templates in `__gnu_cxx` and other internals.

So I'm expecting something like what's being printed in case of template errors, but for *every* class being instantiated by the compiler.
Is it possible? GCC plugins, maybe...

UPD: Well, I have instantiated all the required templates by hand. Seems there is no good way to do this automatically, except inserting some debug printf statements to the GCC code itself.

Comment: Did you try STLFilt: <http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html>? Though originally developed to help you work through template instantiation related errors (and before 'concepts' -- though they are not in place yet as part of the standards), it might just be worth your while. I don't think they have C++11 specific changes since active development stopped a while back. Otherwise, you're left to write your own template compiler of sorts.

Comment: Did you build GCC from source? I seem to recall a lot of debugging dump options and you might be able to get a status message for every template instantiation. It might involve bypassing the driver, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GCC 4.7, I'm assuming you are on a system where you can run clang against your code.   Clang's error messages, specifically with templates are pretty nice.

```
    template
    class Example {
        Example(const T& t) : t_(t) {}
        T& t_;
    };

    int a;
    Example e(a);
```

outputs:

```
    t.cpp:8:14: error: calling a private constructor of class 'Example'
    Example e(a);
                 ^
    t.cpp:3:5: note: implicitly declared private here
        Example(const T& t) : t_(t) {}
        ^
    t.cpp:3:27: error: binding of reference to type 'int' to a value of type 'const int' drops
          qualifiers
        Example(const T& t) : t_(t) {}
                              ^  ~
    t.cpp:8:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'Example::Example' requested here
    Example e(a);
                 ^
    2 errors generated.
```

Comment: How does GCC 4.7 imply Clang, and the question involves code with no errors.

Comment: Ah, I misread it to mean "I need better error messages from some template code."